# Can we find the derivative of modulus function? if yes, then how?

Tags: derivatives

I am confused with the derivatives of modulus function.

Comment: In the reals or in the complex ?

Comment: have you tried the search on this site, this is a rather standard problem...check it out. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839293/derivative-of-fx-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we work in $\mathbb R$, by definition

$$(|x|)'=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}h.$$

First assume $x>0$ and take $h$ small enough that $x+h>0$ (remind that $h<0$ is allowed). Then

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x+h-x}h=1.$$

Similarly when $x<0$ and $x+h<0$,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-(x+h)-(-x)}h=-1.$$

Now for $x=0$,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|0+h|-|0|}h$$
does not exist because the left and right limits ($\mp1$) are different.

Answer (score 1):

The real absolute value function has a derivative for every $x\ne0$, but is not differentiable at $x=0$. Its derivative for $x\ne0$ is given by the step function.

$$\frac{\text{d}|x|}{\text{d}x}=\begin{cases}
-1\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space\space x<0\\
1\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space\space x>0
\end{cases}$$

The subdifferential of $|x|$ at $x=0$ is the interval $[−1,1]$.

The complex absolute value function is continuous everywhere but complex differentiable nowhere because it violates the Cauchy–Riemann equations.

The second derivative of $|x|$ with respect to $x$ is zero everywhere except zero, where it does not exist. As a generalised function, the second derivative may be taken as two times the Dirac delta function.